# How can I store data in a Custom Tag in EXIF with React-Native and read it with Python?

Tags: python, react-native, expo, exif

**Goal:** I need to capture a photo with a camera and store data on it (An Array of strings is sufficient). Then, after transfer the photo to a desktop, I need to retrieve this data.

**Approach:** I am making a React Native app and I am using Expo Framework. The way I found appropriate to store data on the photo, is to store on custom Tags on the EXIF of the photo. I am using Expo-Camera and Expo-Media-Library

I am trying to store the 'yolo' and 'yoloBuf' tags with following code:

```
    //Capture Photo
    let takePic = async () => {
        let options = {
          quality: 1,
          base64: true,
          exif: true,
          additionalExif: {
            yolo: 'bigbig',
            yoloBuf: ['yellow', 'watermelon'],
          }
        };
    
        let newPhoto = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options)
        setPhoto(newPhoto);     
      };
...

    let savePhoto = async () => {

      console.log(photo.exif);  

      MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri).then(() => {
        setPhoto(undefined);
      });
    };
```

The Console.log(photo.exif) is printing the custom tags.

However, on python side, when extracting the EXIF data, I am not seeing the custom tags, neither most of the tags. I've also used a few softwares on Windows to inspect EXIF Tags and I am also not seeing it. Which makes me think that my problem might be on React-Native side.

Awnyway, here it is the relevant code I am using in python:

```
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS

def extract_exif(image_path):
    try:
        with Image.open(image_path) as img:
            exif_data = img._getexif()
            if exif_data is not None:
                print("EXIF Data:")
                for tag, value in exif_data.items():
                    tag_name = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                    print(f"{tag_name}: {value}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error extracting EXIF data: {e}")
```

So, questions:

1. Is EXIF the appropriate field on the photo to store an array of strings on the photo?
2. Am I missing something on React-Native side? Is my problem on saving the photo itself on       MediaLibrary.saveToLibraryAsync(photo.uri)?

Thank you for further help,
Ricardo